# Generic form handler script?

Tags: php, forms

I've been given the task to turn a couple of forms for a charity into online forms to fill out (stuff to sign up for different programs in the charity). The forms I have been give all just have text input fields and I can make the html version.

I was wondering if someone knows of a PHP script that will handle input from the html forms, and chuck them in a text file or database (maybe not database because the fields may change). It doesn't have to be super feature complete, but the charity does not want to use a service such as wufoo.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't append to a text file. Use a database for this. It's the right tool for the job and it can handle changing questions.

Comment: The thing is, it could be a heap of completely different forms that I don't want to create a whole new database schema for. There will only be 1 or 2 people filling them out a month, if that.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a very special circumstance. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out FormMail.

http://www.tectite.com/formmailpage.php

It's a free script that allows you to save your HTML form submissions to a text file (CSV) or have it email the results. There's plenty of documentation/links on the site to help with configuring it.

Answer (score 0):

As over-the-top as this is going to sound, [drupal7](http://drupal.org/) has nice form management right out of the box…er, zip file.

If you've already got PHP and MySQL, the setup time is measured in minutes for a basic install. There's also a simple way of creating custom forms and all sorts of configurations to allow you to use the data that's been collected.

Comment: actually, that sounds like a good idea. the existing website I made them uses drupal... I may have a look into that.